# Pole targets on ik rig dont guide the joint properly

Tags: rigging, inverse-kinematics

I have added 2 pole targets on my rig for the 2 arms and they work as intended, they pull the elbows to the back (where the poles are located). However, i have added 2 similar ones for the knees but they bend to the side for some reason instead of forewards (where the poles are located).

The pole angles on both of the sheen bones are 0 and the thigh bones are properly rolled in edit mode so their x direction is pointing towards the pole. I tried changing the pole angle but that rotates the thigh bone on the z axis and i don't want that. Does anybody know what i might be doing wrong?

https://we.tl/t-QDR8ug5slW

Comment: pls show us all necessary settings or provide blend file. Thanks.

Comment: https://we.tl/t-QDR8ug5slW Here is the file btw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In *Edit* mode, move the knee a bit forward so that Blender knows how it is supposed to bend:

[image]